# Azure data sync from Azure Db to Azure DWH

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, data-warehouse, database-replication, azure-data-sync

I am trying to perform a replication using Azure data sync between an Azure sql database and an Azure SQL Data Warehouse. I have a table with a primary key, identity (1,1). When i try to perform the sync, I receive an error saying something related to a syntax error around "PRIMARY". Is this issue related to how pk's are managed in azure data warehouses or, simply said, this kind of replication is not supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Data Sync synchronizes data between SQL Azure Databases and SQL Server instances only. SQL Azure Data Warehouse is not supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo